# c# large array to independent process

Tags: c#, memory-management

i'ld like to record a video temporarily to memory in a 32-bit C# application. It's not an option to change the application to 64bit. But the application is running on an 64bit OS.

Each image of the video sequence is 5MP big and the sequence consists of 500 pictures. Loading them to memory leads to around 2.5GB memory usage. Which brings the application close to an out of memory exception.

Is there any way to store an array containing all images to an independent process so it can use full 4GB to store the video sequence? If so is it a good idea to do so or is there any best practice dealing with video files in memory?

Comment: You should look into overflowing to disk for this task rather than trying to marshal data between a 32-bit and 64-bit process.

Comment: I also believe that offloading to disk is your best bet here. Alternatively you might look into dynamically compressing the frames in memory (using e.g. JPEG or PNG (if lossless is absolutely necessary)).

Comment: Thanks for your inspirations. Helps me a lot to search into the right direction. So what do you think about solving such a problem with Memory-Mapped Files?